# Error while plotting an array on python

Tags: python, opencv, matrix, plot

I'm working with **python and I'm new**. I **want to plot** two arrays from my code, one of them is plot correctly, but the other one *throws me an error*:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py:4511: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
c /= np.sqrt(np.dot(x, x) * np.dot(y, y))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./track-multiple.py", line 169, in <module>
ax2.xcorr(x2, y2)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 4508, in xcorr
c = np.correlate(x, y, mode=2)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 871, in correlate
return multiarray.correlate2(a, v, mode)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

The code is the next:

```
x1 = np.arange(0,len(colunas[0],1)
y1 = columnas[0]
x2 = np.arange(0,len(filas))
y2 = filas

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.xcorr(x1,y1)
ax1.axhline(0, color='black', lw=2)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
ax2.xcorr(x2,y2)
ax2.axhline(0, color='blue', lw=2)

plt.show()
```

I think the problem is in filas array due his dimension, or I misuse of xcorr method. If I do a print on filas and columnas I get this:

```
filas = 
[[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]

...

[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]]
columnas = 
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  ...  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

The two arrays were created with OpenCV libraries in these sentences:

```
columnas = cv2.reduce(fgmask,0,cv.CV_REDUCE_MAX)
filas = cv2.reduce(fgmask,1,cv.CV_REDUCE_MAX)
```

Waiting ideas!

PD: OK I find how to fix the error, I just convert array filas with:

```
 filas = filas[:,0]
```

But I don't know exactly the reason of the error as well as the fix, can anyone answer my questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is confusion with your variable types.
`x1` and `x2` are N and M long 1D numpy arrays.
`filas` is an N long list of 1 long lists.
`columnas` is a 1 long list containing an M long list.

```
x1 = np.arange(0,len(colunas[0],1)   # N long numpy array
y1 = columnas[0]                     # N long list 
x2 = np.arange(0,len(filas))         # M long numpy array
y2 = filas                           # M long list of 1 long lists
```

Python lists and numpy arrays are different! You can simulate a 2D array in Python with list of lists, but you won't be able to simply slice them vertically (i.e. get one column). But this is exactly what you need.

I think you should decide if you want to use Python or Numpy variable types and be consistent with your choice.

The Python approach:

```
x1 = range(0,len(colunas[0],1)       # N long list
y1 = columnas[0]                     # N long list 
x2 = range(0,len(filas))             # M long list
y2 = [item[0] for item in filas]     # M long list
```

In the last line here, you loop through `filas` (M loops), and for each item (singleton list), you collect the number inside the singleton list.

The Numpy approach:

```
x1 = np.arange(0,len(colunas[0],1)   # N long numpy array
y1 = np.array(columnas[0])           # N long numpy array
x2 = np.arange(0,len(filas))         # M long numpy array
y2 = np.array(filas)[:,0]            # M long numpy array
```

In the last line here, you create a 2D numpy array from your `filas` list of lists, and take the first column of that array with advanced array slicing that is not allowed for lists.